# Printing to multiple output files in java

Tags: java

I have two arrays that I want to print to separate files.  Here's my code:

```
    try {
      PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(
          "Edges.txt"));
      for (i = 0; i < bcount; i++) {
        out.println(b[i][0] + " " + b[i][1]);
      }
      out.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }



    } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
      PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(
          "Nodes.txt"));
      for (i = 0; i < bigbIter; i++) {
        out.println(bigb[i]);
      }
      out.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }



    } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If I only use the first set of try / catch / catch, it works perfectly.  But when I use both it doesn't work, giving me the errors "illegal start of type ... } catch" and "error: class, interface, or enum expected".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you use your IDE's code formatter and it will be obvious you have too many `}`

Comment: I suggest that you don't copy similar code, but rather write a method of writting an array to file

Comment: +1 to using an IDE to format your code. It will help you catch common place errors like this. On a tangent, if you are allowed to use external libraries in this project I am going to recommend you look at the [TeeOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) in [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/). It makes tasks like this easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}



} catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

You have an extra `}`, which throws off the parser and gives you lots of errors.

Comment: Nice catch, I had to re-read your answer(and question) a few times just to find the extra `}`. Stupid brain, not being able to see what is in front of me.

Comment: Ahhhhh so frustrating that's all it was.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should write a method to write to the file. Just pass the file name and data. You should see that you have too many closing brackets, get your IDE to highlight brackets.

Lesson is just don't copy/paste and then edit the catch block when you want it again!

Edit: Also in java 7 you can have multiple catches in one block, it is better to do this:

```
catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException e)
{
}
```